# specifying test framework with newgem

Tags: ruby, newgem

```
> jruby -S newgem testgem --simple -T test_unit
invalid option: -T
```

Newgem v1.5.1

Also tried

```
> jruby -S newgem testgem --simple --test-with=test_unit
invalid option: --test-with=test_unit
```

Also tried MRI.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it manually:

- mkdir test
- Add test/test_helper.rb and test/my_class_test.rb
- Add the following to the Rakefile:

```
    task :default => :test
    desc "Run all Unit tests"
    task :test do
        require 'rake/runtest'
        Rake.run_tests 'test/*.rb'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the --simple and --test-with options are incompatible, as the --simple option uses a different generator script that doesn't support all the extra options that the "standard" generator supports.

Comment: when I try > newgem testgem -T test_unit I get "can't convert nil into String"